# How can I get the pervious version for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I need to check a bug in Google Chrome for specific version like 14.0.802.30. How can I get the pervious version for that? Also, how can I switch off automatic update functionailty of Chrome?

Answer (score -1):

Some old Chrome-Versions can be found on [oldapps.com](http://www.oldapps.com/google_chrome.php) if you can't find the version there, you can maybe use the corresponding [Chromium](http://www.chromium.org/Home) release? Its basically Chrome minus the Google-Spyware. For Operating Systems other than linux you have to build your own version tough (easy to follow instructions are published on the website).

Chromium-Releases can be found [here](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/releases/)

Comment: @GaryWang Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't leave a comment just to say “thank you”. If this answer solved your problem [mark this answer as accepted.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)